# SELECT * FROM DB where X = Y. If nothing = Y, I need an else statement to do something

Tags: php, sql, database, select, if-statement

The problem is if you `$_POST['username']` contains a username that is present in the database, the script works well. If the username is mistyped or anything else is typed besides what will be found in the database, it locks up.

Is there a way to structure `SELECT` to an "else" type statement that way when a typo happens it will "do this"...

Thanks in advance

```
include('includes/config.php');
if($_REQUEST['do'] == 'login') {
   $postusername = $_POST['username'];
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $sqlusers WHERE 
                            username = '$postusername'");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
      if($_POST['username'] == $row['username'] && 
         $_POST['password'] == $row['password']){

         $logged_username = $row['username'];
         $_SESSION['username']= $logged_username;     
         $_SESSION['active']=1;
         session_write_close;
         //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out`
         header("location:/index.php"); 
      }
      else {        
         header("Location:login.php?errorMssg=".urlencode("Your Login 
                  Information is incorrect!!"));
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: please see changes I made...

```
<?php
include('includes/config.php');
if($_REQUEST['do'] == 'login') {
   //check if username and password set
   if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

     $postusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
     $postpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $sqlusers WHERE username = '$postusername' and password = '$postpassword' ");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
           $logged_username = $postusername;
           $_SESSION['username']= $postusername;     
           $_SESSION['active']=1;
           session_write_close;
           //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out`
           header("location:/index.php");
           exit;
        }
        else {        
           header("Location:login.php?errorMssg=".urlencode("Your Login 
                    Information is incorrect!!"));
          exit;
        }

   }else{
           header("Location:login.php?errorMssg=".urlencode("Enter Username and Password"));
           exit;
   }
}
```

Update: Prepared statement

```
<?php
include('includes/config.php');
if($_REQUEST['do'] == 'login') {
   //check if username and password set
   if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM $sqlusers WHERE username = ? and password = ? ");
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

        if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0){
           $logged_username = $postusername;
           $_SESSION['username']= $postusername;     
           $_SESSION['active']=1;
           session_write_close;
           //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out`
           header("location:/index.php");
           exit;
        }
        else {        
           header("Location:login.php?errorMssg=".urlencode("Your Login 
                    Information is incorrect!!"));
          exit;
        }

   }else{
           header("Location:login.php?errorMssg=".urlencode("Enter Username and Password"));
           exit;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string` — used parametrized queries instead!

Comment: Thanks Akam! The 2nd rendition works partially. It returns to the login.php if either $_POST['username'] or $_POST['password'] is empty. However, if both are left empty. your code still logs a blank user into the session..

Comment: How can I extract the username variable and insert it into the session wit this prepared satement?

    $_SESSION['username']= $???

Comment: @DustyJoe: use `$postusername` its posted by user, why you need to extract it? if username and password was correct then the post username is the one that you need it

Comment: @Akam. I am going to use $_SESSION['username'] to display a welcome message (Welcome back, $_SESSION['username']) in essence. The problem I see using $_POST['username'] is if when they registered they used the name 'TestGuyRegistrant'.. and when they logged in if they used all lowercase or a combination of both the $_POST would reflect that. Which is why I like to pull from the database and let the username stored in the database = $_SESSION['username'] so their welcome message shows their name as they registered it. Or if I wanted to pull the "userid" tied to the user from the database.

Comment: @DustyJoe: if user and password are correct then it means that postuser is correct, otherwise, the S_SESSION will not be set

Comment: @Akam: You are correct. However it if the user types their login information in all LOWERCASE letters and they registered with all UPERCASE letters, the $_POST will reflect all LOWERCASE letters and not all UPPERCASE or whatever is stored in the database. Basically if I registered with a username of "DustyJOE" and log into the site by typing my username as "dustyjoe". I need to pull from the database the registered username so I can display the proper capitalization of their user name in my welcome message as the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: @DustyJoe you can't get the username based on postuser at that case! because in sql query we said where username = $postuser

Answer (score 0):

queries return false if they fail, so you can use code like

`$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);`

and then something like

```
if ($result != false)
    do some crap
else
    do some other crap
```

the standard for finding SQL errors in code seem to be

`$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $sqlusers WHERE username = '$postusername'") or die (mysqli_error($con));`

but I dont know if that was what you were asking.

ON A RELATED NOTE

Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please fix it
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you should escape data sent by user to defend against hackers sql injection attacks
2. You should keep users password save and hash them before you store them to the database. Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php
3. You have not written part what to do, if db result is empty (no user with given login)

Try this:

```
<?php
include('includes/config.php');
if ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'login')
{
    $postusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $sqlusers WHERE username = '$postusername'");
    if (!$result)
    {
        // handle error
    }

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row && $_POST['password'] == $row['password'])
    {
        $logged_username = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $logged_username;
        $_SESSION['active'] = 1;
        session_write_close;
        //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out`
        header("location:/index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location:login.php?errorMssg=" . urlencode("Your Login Information is incorrect!!"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is :

```
  SELECT * FROM $sqlusers WHERE username = '$postusername'
```

As mentioned in your question, if "nothing = Y", ie, if no username in the table matches the posted username, the query will return an empty result set. In simple PHP terms, 'if nothing in db = username', is translated to :

```
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) { // no rows matches the posted username (nothing = Y, in your words)
       //handle your error here
   } else { // ie, X = Y in your words
        // the while loop to check password goes here
    }
```